# error:14090086:SSL certificate verify failed on Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, nginx, homestead

Before anything, I have already done a deep search inside Stackoverflow and tried many answers posted here. But, I havent found anyone with this problem on Homestead, actually, one of the popular solutions is: "go to homestead".

This is the full error:

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

I already: 
downloaded an updated `cert.pem` (with `wget`) and moved it to **/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem**.
Uncommented the `php.ini` line with the `openssl.cacert` and updated that path (with the one above).

That path, comes from this command:

```
php -r "var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());"
```

This is my **.env** file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mailaccount
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Of course, after every update I did a `php artisan config:cache` and also restarted nginx.

I'm working on a fresh Homestead installation, with no other changes.

Does anybody else had this problem on **Laravel's Homestead**? is pretty weird since I seem to be the only one.

I hope anyone can help me! I don't know what else to try.

Edit:

I don't want to use the following workaround:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

I need to solve this in a proper way, since in the future I have to administrate the server.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So many weird problems with smtp, I just move to Mailgun, and now, no more issues anymore.